# How to avoid concurrent access to payment link in my website

Tags: java, mysql, database, concurrency, struts2

I am using mysql InnoDB and struts2 for developing my website. When a user want to use a product, he will be send an invoice to his inbox and with that link he can pay the money.

The problem I have to solve is: when a user opens the link in two sessions and tries to pay for both, I have to allow only one transaction. And if allowed transaction gets a problem like browser closure or some other issue, things will go into deadlock condition. I have to avoid this and allow the next transactions.

Please suggest me how to achieve this?

Comment: I think you will have to add a life time for each session to prevent deadlocks (just like in the one being used by bank's sites)...

Comment: @Amit --> Sorry, I am unable to get what you are coming to say, Please can you say it easy.

Comment: In bank sites, how they are maintaining concurrency. Can anyone explain it, please.

Comment: using unique sessionids all the sessions have  fix life time. Once the time is over the session is expired. In that case if one session is active you can deny all the attempts to that session. If browser closes in between the session, session will automatically expire after its life time. Now if the payment was not done due to any reason i.e. session expire or browser closed, User can simply reclick on the link and restart the process...

Comment: Ya got it. Thank you @Amit. I thought of keeping a timestamp and checks for specific amount of time and if exceeds allow to access else deny access until that time exceeds.

Comment: I am glad it helped, Just added an answer by merging both the comments, You can upvote and accept that if it was helpful for you..

Comment: @Amit --> am not having reputation to upvote but can accept and also having another doubt, please check comments section of your answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you will have to add a life time for each session to prevent deadlocks (just like in the one being used by bank's sites) and you can do that using unique sessionids. All the sessions have fix life time. Once the time is over the session is expired.

In that case if one session is active you can deny all the attempts to that session. If browser closes in between the session, session will automatically expire after its life time. Now if the payment was not done due to any reason i.e. session expire or browser closed, User can simply re-click on the link and restart the process.

Hope it helps,

Comment: --> Is this the method Banks too using? and What about transactions and locking in Mysql. Can anyone clear my doubt??Please.

Comment: Never worked on any bank's site. However as programmer you can imagine what should be going behind the scenes when the webpage says "Your session has expired, please login again"...  Its fun being a programmer you should try to imagine what should be actually happening when you click on a button on a web site or App.